# Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed

Tags: ros

I am trying to install the [ego-planner package](https://github.com/ZJU-FAST-Lab/ego-planner). When I run `catkin_make`, I get an error. I am running ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04. How do I fix this? This is the output I get (I have included most of the output, because I wasn't sure what was relevant. Please feel free to edit my question and remove unnecessary lines):

```
...
-- ==> add_subdirectory(uav_simulator/so3_quadrotor_simulator)
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'Eigen3' but neither 'Eigen3_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor
  'Eigen3_LIBRARIES' is defined.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  uav_simulator/so3_quadrotor_simulator/CMakeLists.txt:29 (catkin_package)


CMake Warning at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'system_lib' but neither
  'system_lib_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor 'system_lib_LIBRARIES' is defined.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  uav_simulator/so3_quadrotor_simulator/CMakeLists.txt:29 (catkin_package)


-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rviz_plugins'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(uav_simulator/Utils/rviz_plugins)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'system_lib' but neither
  'system_lib_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor 'system_lib_LIBRARIES' is defined.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  uav_simulator/Utils/rviz_plugins/CMakeLists.txt:12 (catkin_package)


-- Using Qt5 based on the rviz_QT_VERSION: 5.9.5
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'waypoint_generator'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(uav_simulator/Utils/waypoint_generator)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Configuring done
CMake Warning (dev) at uav_simulator/Utils/multi_map_server/CMakeLists.txt:167 (add_dependencies):
  Policy CMP0046 is not set: Error on non-existent dependency in
  add_dependencies.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0046" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The dependency target "multi_map_server_messages_cpp" of target
  "multi_map_visualization" does not exist.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/kadhir/catkin_ws/src/ego-planner/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/kadhir/catkin_ws/src/ego-planner/build"
####
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target _quadrotor_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Odometry
[  0%] Built target _quadrotor_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_StatusData
[  0%] Built target _quadrotor_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Serial
[  0%] Built target _quadrotor_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_LQRTrajectory
[  0%] Built target _quadrotor_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PPROutputData
[  0%] Built target _quadrotor_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PolynomialTrajectory
[  0%] Built target _quadrotor_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PositionCommand
[  0%] Built target _quadrotor_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_OutputData
[  0%] Built target _quadrotor_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SO3Command
[  0%] Built target _quadrotor_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Gains
[  0%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target _quadrotor_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Corrections
[  0%] Built target _quadrotor_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_AuxCommand
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target _quadrotor_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_TRPYCommand
[  0%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  1%] Built target pose_utils
[  2%] Built target random_forest
[  4%] Built target plan_env
[  4%] Built target _multi_map_server_generate_messages_check_deps_MultiSparseMap3D
[  4%] Built target _multi_map_server_generate_messages_check_deps_MultiOccupancyGrid
[  4%] Built target _multi_map_server_generate_messages_check_deps_VerticalOccupancyGridList
[  4%] Built target _multi_map_server_generate_messages_check_deps_SparseMap3D
[  5%] Built target SO3Control
[  7%] Built target mockamap_node
[  7%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  7%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  7%] Built target _ego_planner_generate_messages_check_deps_Bspline
[  7%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  7%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  7%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  7%] Built target _ego_planner_generate_messages_check_deps_DataDisp
[  8%] Built target quadrotor_dynamics
[ 17%] Built target quadrotor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 19%] Built target waypoint_generator
[ 27%] Built target quadrotor_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 35%] Built target quadrotor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 43%] Built target quadrotor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 52%] Built target quadrotor_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 55%] Built target multi_map_server_generate_messages_cpp
[ 58%] Built target multi_map_server_generate_messages_py
[ 59%] Built target path_searching
[ 61%] Built target multi_map_server_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 65%] Built target multi_map_server_generate_messages_lisp
[ 66%] Built target ego_planner_generate_messages_lisp
[ 67%] Built target ego_planner_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 69%] Built target multi_map_server_generate_messages_eus
[ 70%] Built target ego_planner_generate_messages_cpp
[ 72%] Built target ego_planner_generate_messages_py
[ 75%] Built target ego_planner_generate_messages_eus
[ 75%] Built target quadrotor_msgs_generate_messages
[ 76%] Built target encode_msgs
[ 77%] Built target decode_msgs
[ 77%] Built target multi_map_server_generate_messages
[ 77%] Built target ego_planner_generate_messages
[ 79%] Built target bspline_opt
[ 80%] Built target multi_map_visualization
[ 80%] Building CXX object uav_simulator/Utils/odom_visualization/CMakeFiles/odom_visualization.dir/src/odom_visualization.cpp.o
[ 81%] Built target pcl_render_node
[ 82%] Built target control_example
Scanning dependencies of target traj_utils
[ 83%] Built target so3_control_nodelet
[ 84%] Built target quadrotor_simulator_so3
[ 93%] Built target rviz_plugins
[ 94%] Building CXX object planner/traj_utils/CMakeFiles/traj_utils.dir/src/polynomial_traj.cpp.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object planner/traj_utils/CMakeFiles/traj_utils.dir/src/planning_visualization.cpp.o
In file included from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:32:0,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/kadhir/catkin_ws/src/ego-planner/src/uav_simulator/Utils/odom_visualization/src/odom_visualization.cpp:3:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/publisher.h:53:52: warning: defaulted and deleted functions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
     Publisher& operator=(const Publisher& other) = default;
                                                    ^
In file included from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:33:0,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/kadhir/catkin_ws/src/ego-planner/src/uav_simulator/Utils/odom_visualization/src/odom_visualization.cpp:3:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/subscriber.h:52:52: warning: defaulted and deleted functions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
   Subscriber& operator=(const Subscriber& other) = default;
                                                    ^
In file included from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:34:0,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/kadhir/catkin_ws/src/ego-planner/src/uav_simulator/Utils/odom_visualization/src/odom_visualization.cpp:3:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/service_server.h:51:58: warning: defaulted and deleted functions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
   ServiceServer& operator=(const ServiceServer& other) = default;
                                                          ^
In file included from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:35:0,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/kadhir/catkin_ws/src/ego-planner/src/uav_simulator/Utils/odom_visualization/src/odom_visualization.cpp:3:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/service_client.h:49:58: warning: defaulted and deleted functions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
   ServiceClient& operator=(const ServiceClient& other) = default;
                                                          ^
In file included from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:36:0,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/kadhir/catkin_ws/src/ego-planner/src/uav_simulator/Utils/odom_visualization/src/odom_visualization.cpp:3:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/timer.h:52:42: warning: defaulted and deleted functions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
   Timer& operator=(const Timer& other) = default;
                                          ^
In file included from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:38:0,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/kadhir/catkin_ws/src/ego-planner/src/uav_simulator/Utils/odom_visualization/src/odom_visualization.cpp:3:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/wall_timer.h:52:50: warning: defaulted and deleted functions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
   WallTimer& operator=(const WallTimer& other) = default;
                                                  ^
In file included from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:39:0,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/kadhir/catkin_ws/src/ego-planner/src/uav_simulator/Utils/odom_visualization/src/odom_visualization.cpp:3:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/steady_timer.h:52:54: warning: defaulted and deleted functions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
   SteadyTimer& operator=(const SteadyTimer& other) = default;
                                                      ^
In file included from /opt/ros/melodic/include/tf/transform_broadcaster.h:36:0,
                 from /home/kadhir/catkin_ws/src/ego-planner/src/uav_simulator/Utils/odom_visualization/src/odom_visualization.cpp:4:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/tf/tf.h:354:8: error: ‘shared_ptr’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
   std::shared_ptr<tf2_ros::Buffer> getTF2BufferPtr() { return tf2_buffer_ptr_;};
        ^
/opt/ros/melodic/include/tf/tf.h:403:8: error: ‘shared_ptr’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
   std::shared_ptr<tf2_ros::Buffer> tf2_buffer_ptr_;
        ^
/opt/ros/melodic/include/tf/tf.h: In member function ‘ros::Duration tf::Transformer::getCacheLength()’:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/tf/tf.h:331:43: error: ‘tf2_buffer_ptr_’ was not declared in this scope
   ros::Duration getCacheLength() { return tf2_buffer_ptr_->getCacheLength();}
                                           ^
/opt/ros/melodic/include/tf/tf.h: In member function ‘void tf::Transformer::setUsingDedicatedThread(bool)’:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/tf/tf.h:349:46: error: ‘tf2_buffer_ptr_’ was not declared in this scope
   void setUsingDedicatedThread(bool value) { tf2_buffer_ptr_->setUsingDedicatedThread(value);};
                                              ^
/opt/ros/melodic/include/tf/tf.h: In member function ‘bool tf::Transformer::isUsingDedicatedThread()’:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/tf/tf.h:351:42: error: ‘tf2_buffer_ptr_’ was not declared in this scope
   bool isUsingDedicatedThread() { return tf2_buffer_ptr_->isUsingDedicatedThread();};
                                          ^
uav_simulator/Utils/odom_visualization/CMakeFiles/odom_visualization.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'uav_simulator/Utils/odom_visualization/CMakeFiles/odom_visualization.dir/src/odom_visualization.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [uav_simulator/Utils/odom_visualization/CMakeFiles/odom_visualization.dir/src/odom_visualization.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4424: recipe for target 'uav_simulator/Utils/odom_visualization/CMakeFiles/odom_visualization.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [uav_simulator/Utils/odom_visualization/CMakeFiles/odom_visualization.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 94%] Linking CXX shared library /home/kadhir/catkin_ws/src/ego-planner/devel/lib/libtraj_utils.so
[ 94%] Built target traj_utils
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

Comment: Did you try to put a 
#include <memory>
at top of https://github.com/ZJU-FAST-Lab/ego-planner/blob/master/src/uav_simulator/Utils/odom_visualization/src/odom_visualization.cpp

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately, it didn't work